# How to disable weird scrolling change in Windows 8.1 Explorer

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, mouse, scrolling, touchscreen

I've been having this issue where every time I scroll in a Windows Explorer window using my touchpad the cursor changes to this weird dot. For a lack of better words it just scrolls funny in explorer as if I'm controlling it with a touchscreen (my computer has this option but I disabled it). I circled what the cursor changes to in red.

[image]

When I scroll all the way to the top the actual window moves down like it's being pulled from a touch control and it's really frustrating. Not to mention the cursor moves to the center of the window as soon as you start scrolling, so you lose the placement there.

I heard this could be related to Windows Flicks but I haven't been able to find anything to remove it while in Windows 8.1 since there is no Flicks tab in the Pen & Touch section of the control panel. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you check all the Synaptics settings (or whatever touchpad you have)?

Answer (score 2):

If you're still looking for an answer:
Go to registry and under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch set Bouncing to 0.
Source: [How to disable window over scroll bump when scrolling with touch screen?](http://www.reddit.com/r/windows8/comments/2ltxzk/how_to_disable_window_overscroll_bump_when/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.